# A Bound on the Dimensions of Certain Types of Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $V$ be a $4$-dimensional vector space over the complex numbers, and let $S$ be a subspace of the endomorphisms of $V$ such that the elements of $S$ commute.

If there exists an element in $S$ that has at least two distinct eigenvalues, is the dimension of $S$ at most $4$? If so (or if not), why?

An example of such a subspace of dimension $5$ that does not have an element with at least two distinct eigenvalues is the set of matrices of the form
$$\left(\begin{matrix}
a & 0 & c & d \\
0 & a & e & f \\
0 & 0 & a & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & a 
\end{matrix}\right) .$$

Comment: I see where this is coming from, but I would guess not. Can't find a counterexample at the moment though.

Answer (score 3):

By an old theorem of Schur (see [this simple proof in an early paper by the late great Maryam Mirzakhani](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2589084?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents)), the maximal number of linearly independent linear endomorphisms of $\mathbb{C}^n$ is $N(n) = \lfloor n^2/4 \rfloor + 1$. Your example gives the maximum dimension $N(4)=5$. However, if some matrix $A \in S$ has two different eigenvalues, then $S$ will be reducible since every matrix in $S$ has these different eigenspaces of $A$ as invariant subspaces. For $n<4$, one always has $N(n) = n$, so the maximum dimension in that case is $4$.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the theorem and for this nice application.